# Kann jemand mir helfen, den Bühnentext dieses Schauspielers zu verstehen?

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AsBMeHKTNc8&t=1370s

Dies ist ein Clip von dem deutschen Musical „Elisabeth“. Es beginnt um 22: 50 und endet um 22: 56, nur 6 Sekunden.

Der Schauspieler sagt etwas wie „Eh du, ..., lass los, ...“, aber ich kann es leider nicht bestimmen. (Es konnte auch sein, dass er Italienische spricht...)

Answer (score 3):

Er improvisiert eine Anmache ("Kobern") vor einem Bordell und spricht dabei anscheinend jemanden aus dem Publikum an. Ich denke nicht, dass es eine Rolle spielt, was genau er sagt. Ich höre:

> He du! Ja, ich seh dich, dich mein ich! Hast du Lust? Ich seh's dir ... Ja, lass die Frau. Komm, such dir aus!

---

He's extemporizing a come-on in front of a brothel, I don't think it matters at all what he's saying. I'm hearing:

> He du! Ja, ich seh dich, dich mein ich! Hast du Lust? Ich seh's dir ... Ja, lass die Frau. Komm, such dir aus!

Comment: Yes, I agree that it doesn’t really matter much to the play. I am just curious about what he actually says. Thank you!

Comment: [HIer](https://www.lyrix.at/t/elisabeth-alle-song-texte-800) ist der Text des Musicals. Luchenis Worte erscheinen darin nicht, sie werden in den Text von FRAU WOLF & MÄDCHEN hineingesprochen (nach der Stelle "Tatjana fängt im Bett
zu fluchen an")..